# Way to get file name and parent directory name

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am building an application a react/redux based application and looking for a best way to get parent directory and filename form url. URL do not have domain name so it only have the path after the domain name for eg

```
/directory1/index.html?v=1.1
// need to get /directory1/index.html?v=1.1

directory1/directory2/dircetory3/index.html?v=1.1
// need to get directory2/index.html?v=1.1

/index.html?v=1.1
// need to get only index.html?v=1.1 as no parent directory is available
```

> /immediateParentDirectory/filename.html

I tried creating a regex but want able to just wanted to confirm if there is already existing node module that does that before I reinvent the wheel

Comment: Maybe just `path.slice(0, path.indexOf('?'))` ?

Comment: Willnot give me dircetory name so I am looking to get ParentDirectory/filename.js?v=1.1
So immediate parent directory + filename

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear from your example what you need.

Comment: My Bad , Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.split('/')` the URL on the forward slash character `/`. Then `.slice(-2)` to get the last 2 items from the split items. Then `.join('/')` those two items back together with a slash.

```js
function parentPath(url) {
  return url.split('/').slice(-2).join('/')
}

console.log(parentPath('/directory1/index.html?v=1.1'))    
console.log(parentPath('directory1/directory2/dircetory3/index.html?v=1.1'))    
console.log(parentPath('/index.html?v=1.1'))
console.log(parentPath('index.html?v=1.1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`path.dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path) and [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext):

```
function doSomething(p) {
  const dir = path.dirname(p);
  // takes care of `foo` and `/foo`
  if (dir === '.' || dir === '/') {
    return p;
  }

  return path.basename(dir) + '/' + path.basename(p);
}
```

This assumes that you are not having paths with relative sections, such as `foo/bar/..baz/` or `./foo`.

It's unclear to me whether you want a leading `/` or not, but that's also easy to add or remove by checking `result[0] === '/'`.